# Java Bank Account class that keeps track of transactions that occur within a certain time range

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

For a school java programming assignment (grade 11 - only been learning java for around 3 months now) I have to create a class that represents a bank account. The program should include the account number, balance of the account, and all of the logic behind withdrawing and depositing. So far I have everything required by the assignment except I am having trouble figuring out how to use an array list (provided by my teacher) to return all transactions within a certain DateTime range as well as sort these transactions from oldest to newest.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class BankAccount {

//Instance Variables 
String accountNumber;
double balance; 
double withdrawalFee; 
double annualInterestRate; 
String description;
LocalDateTime transactionTime; 
LocalDateTime startTime; 
LocalDateTime endTime; 

//Accessors and Mutators 
public String getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public double getWithdrawalFee() {
    return withdrawalFee; 
}

public void setWithdrawalFee(double withdrawalFee) {
    this.withdrawalFee = withdrawalFee; 
}

public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate;
}

public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate; 
}

//Constructors 
public BankAccount(String accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber; 
}

public BankAccount(String accountNumber, double initialBalance) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber; 
    balance = initialBalance;
}

public BankAccount(String accountNumber, double balance, double withdrawalFee, double               annualInterestRate) {
this.accountNumber = accountNumber; 
this.balance = balance; 
this.withdrawalFee = withdrawalFee; 
this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
}

//Public Methods
public ArrayList<Transaction> getTransactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

public void deposit(double amount) {
    this.balance = balance + amount;
    getTransactions.add(new Transaction(amount));
}

public void deposit(LocalDateTime transactionTime, double amount, String description) {
    this.balance = balance + amount;
    this.description = description; 
    this.transactionTime = transactionTime;
    getTransactions.add(new Transaction(transactionTime, amount, description));
}

public void deposit(double amount, String description) {
    this.balance = balance + amount;
    this.description = description; 
    getTransactions.add(new Transaction(amount, description));
}

public void withdraw(double amount) {
    this.balance = balance - amount; 
    getTransactions.add(new Transaction(amount));
}

public void withdraw(LocalDateTime transactionTime, double amount, String description) {
    this.balance = balance - amount - withdrawalFee;
    this.description = description; 
    this.transactionTime = transactionTime;
    getTransactions.add(new Transaction(transactionTime, amount, description));
}

public void withdraw(double amount, String description) {
    this.balance = balance - amount - withdrawalFee;
    this.description = description; 
    getTransactions.add(new Transaction(amount, description));
}


//Array list that should return all transactions that occur within the DateTime range
//Transactions will be sorted from oldest to newest
//If startTime is null, then assume that there is no lower bound
//If endTime is null, then assume that there is no upper bound
public ArrayList<Transaction> getTransactions(LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime endTime){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < getTransactions.size() ; i++) {
    
        
    }
}



boolean isOverDrawn() {
    if(this.balance < 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public String toString() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    if(balance >= 0) {
        return "BankAccount " + accountNumber + ": " + "$"+df.format(balance);
    } else {
        return "BankAccount " + accountNumber + ": " + "("+"$"+df.format(balance*-1)+")";
    }

}


}
```

Here is the transaction class:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Transaction {

    LocalDateTime transactionTime;
    double amount;
    String description;
 
    public Transaction(LocalDateTime transactionTime, double amount, String description){
        this.transactionTime = transactionTime;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Transaction(double amount) {
        this.transactionTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.amount = amount;
    }    
    
    public Transaction(double amount, String description){
        this.transactionTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.amount = amount; 
        this.description = description; 
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getTransactionTime(){
        return transactionTime;
    }

    public double getAmount(){
        return amount;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().toString() + ":" + this.transactionTime.toString();
    }

}
```

Lastly here is the JUnit test my code needs to pass:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class BankAccountImprovedTester extends junit.framework.TestCase
{

    BankAccount chequing1;
    BankAccount chequing2;
    BankAccount chequing3;

    Transaction t1;
    
    protected void setUp()
    {
        chequing1 = new BankAccount("chequing1");
        chequing2 = new BankAccount("chequing2", 100);
        chequing3 = new BankAccount("chequing3", 100, 2.00, 5.0);        
    }
    
    public void testAccessors()
    {
        assertEquals("chequing2",  chequing2.getAccountNumber());
        assertEquals(100.0,  chequing2.getBalance(), 0);
        assertEquals(5.0,  chequing3.getAnnualInterestRate(), 0);
        assertEquals(2.0,  chequing3.getWithdrawalFee(), 0);
    }

    public void testMutators()
    {
        //test for setters
        chequing1.setWithdrawalFee(3.0);
        chequing1.setAnnualInterestRate(4.0);
        assertEquals(3.0,  chequing1.getWithdrawalFee(), 0);
        assertEquals(4.0,  chequing1.getAnnualInterestRate(), 0);
    }

    public void testDeposits()
    {                   
        //test various deposits and withdrawals
        chequing1.setWithdrawalFee(3.0);
    
        chequing1.deposit(500, "deposit 1");
        assertEquals(500.0,  chequing1.getBalance(), 0);
        
        chequing1.withdraw(200, "withdrawal 1");
        assertEquals(297.0,  chequing1.getBalance(), 0);            
        assertEquals(false,  chequing1.isOverDrawn());
                
        chequing1.withdraw(300,"withdrawal 2");
        assertEquals(-6.0,  chequing1.getBalance(), 0);
        assertEquals(true,  chequing1.isOverDrawn());
    
        chequing2.deposit(0.42, "deposit 2");
        assertEquals(100.42,  chequing2.getBalance(), 0.00);
        chequing2.deposit(0.001,  "deposit 3");
        assertEquals(100.421,  chequing2.getBalance(), 0.001);
    
    }

    public void testToString() {
    
        assertEquals("BankAccount chequing1: $0.00",  chequing1.toString());
        assertEquals("BankAccount chequing2: $100.00",  chequing2.toString());
    
        chequing2.deposit(0.42,  "deposit 1");
        assertEquals("BankAccount chequing2: $100.42",  chequing2.toString());

        chequing2.deposit(0.001, "deposit 2");
        assertEquals("BankAccount chequing2: $100.42",  chequing2.toString());

        BankAccount chequing4 = new BankAccount("chequing4", -100);
        assertEquals("BankAccount chequing4: ($100.00)",  chequing4.toString());
    }

    public void testGetTransactions()
    {
        chequing1.setWithdrawalFee(3.0);
    
        LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.of(2000, 12, 31);
        LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.of(14, 15, 30);        
        LocalDateTime dt1 = LocalDateTime.of(d1, t1);
        chequing1.deposit(dt1, 600, "deposit 1");
            
        LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.of(2001, 01, 02);
        LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.of(14, 15, 30);        
        LocalDateTime dt2 = LocalDateTime.of(d2, t2);
        chequing1.withdraw(dt2, 200, "withdrawal 1");
    
        LocalDate d3 = LocalDate.of(2001, 01, 01);
        LocalTime t3 = LocalTime.of(14, 15, 30);        
        LocalDateTime dt3 = LocalDateTime.of(d3, t3);
        chequing1.withdraw(dt3, 300, "withdrawal 2");

        LocalDate d4 = LocalDate.of(2001, 01, 03);
        LocalTime t4 = LocalTime.of(14, 15, 30);        
        LocalDateTime dt4 = LocalDateTime.of(d4, t4);
        chequing1.deposit(dt4, 100, "deposit 2");
    
        //order should be: ["deposit 1"], ["withdrawal 2"], ["withdrawal 1"], ["deposit 2"]
    
        ArrayList<Transaction> trans1 = chequing1.getTransactions(null, null);
        assertEquals(4, trans1.size());
        assertEquals("withdrawal 1", trans1.get(2).getDescription());

        ArrayList<Transaction> trans2 = chequing1.getTransactions(dt2, null);
        assertEquals(2, trans2.size());
        assertEquals("withdrawal 1", trans2.get(0).getDescription());

        ArrayList<Transaction> trans3 = chequing1.getTransactions(null, dt3);
        assertEquals(2, trans3.size());
        assertEquals("withdrawal 2", trans3.get(1).getDescription());

        ArrayList<Transaction> trans4 = chequing1.getTransactions(dt3, dt2);
        assertEquals(2, trans4.size());         
    
        //test if transactions without dateTime will be added to end of list
        chequing1.deposit(50);
        chequing1.withdraw(50);
        ArrayList<Transaction> trans5 = chequing1.getTransactions(null, null);
        assertEquals(6, trans5.size());
      
        //test if transactions without dateTime have a dateTime equivalent to 'now'
        assertEquals(false,     LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(trans5.get(5).getTransactionTime()));
        assertEquals(false, trans5.get(5).getTransactionTime() == null);
    
        //test if transactions are returned in correct order
        for (int i = 0; i < trans5.size() - 1; i++) {
            Transaction earlierTranscation = trans5.get(i);
            Transaction laterTranscation = trans5.get(i+1);
            assertEquals(false, (laterTranscation.getTransactionTime().isBefore(earlierTranscation.getTransactionTime())));            
        }
    
    


    }

}
```

I know this is a lot to ask but I've been stuck on this part of the assignment for a couple days now, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You might want to consider shortening the code here to a [mre]. Otherwise we have to read through a lot of irrelevant code to give you hints towards what seems like a simple question.

Comment: Oh okay I see, sorry about that I'm pretty new to this website. I'll try shortening it - thanks for the response.

Comment: No problem. Also this question seems like it can be broken down into three subproblems: - Checking if a date lies between two others - Filtering a list - Sorting a list. Have you considered these individually?

Answer (score 0):

- First problem - filtering a list:

You want to return a **new** `ArrayList` based on the existing instance variable list (`getTransactions`) in the `BankAccount` for the Transactions that satisfy the constraints

```
ArrayList<Transaction> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < getTransactions.size() ; i++) {
    Transaction currentTransaction = getTransactions.get(i);
    //cater for if no lower bound or if the current transaction is after the lower bound
    boolean pastStart = (startTime == null || currentTransaction.isAfter(startTime));

    //cater for if no upper bound or if the current transaction is before the upper bound
    boolean beforeEnd = (endTime == null || currentTransaction.isBefore(endTime));

    //If both are true add to the return list
    if (pastStart && beforeEnd) {
        returnList.add(transaction);
    }
}

Collections.sort(returnList);
return returnList;
```

- Second problem - sorting the list

For the line `Collections.sort(returnList)` you'll need `Transaction` class to implement the `Comparable` interface - was this covered in your work?

- Enhancement

Also the for loop could be simplified to use lambdas in Java 8 or at least use an enhanced "for each" loop but I kept it as a for loop with indexes as per your original question

Comment: So you're saying I would need to provide a comparator in the transaction class? If you are, my teacher mentioned that we could do this but it won't be officially taught to us until next year (grade 12).

Comment: You can either get `Transaction` to implement `Comparable` or you can provide a `Comparator` implementation to the call to `Collections`. Either one can then make use of the `compareTo` method in the `LocalDateTime` class.   i.e. you could do `Collections.sort(returnList, (tOne, tTwo) -> tOne.getTransactionTime().compareTo(tTwo.getTransactionTime()));`
(watch out for `null`s)

Comment: Did this help @dremmy10 ?